# MySQL: SQL Query performance improvement help needed

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Need some help from MySQL experts to improve the execution time of the following query. It currently takes about 1 hour 25 minutes each night and growing a few minutes each day as more data is added to the rsdata and trdata tables. The other 3 tables are static.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Table sizes are:

```
rsdata - 480,566 rows / 130.4 MiB
trdata - 522,506 rows / 64.3 MiB
module - 1,458 rows / 164 KiB
variantgates - 87 rows / 8 KiB
testatussequence - 8 rows / 2.3 KiB
```

The query:

```
select distinct
rsdata.rs_variant,
rsdata.weeknumber,
rsdata.rs_moduleid,
rsdata.rs_objectidentifier,
trdata.tr_objectidentifier,
trdata.tr_testversion,
trdata.tr_plannedgate,
trdata.tr_vnvmethod,
testatussequence.tesequencenr,
trdata.tr_testexecutionstatus
from rsdata,
trdata,
module,
variantgates,
testatussequence
where rsdata.weeknumber='1408'
and rsdata.rs_moduleid = module.moduleid
and rsdata.rs_reviewstatus != 'Obsolete'
and rsdata.rs_reviewstatus != 'Rejected'
and rsdata.rs_introbjectidentifieralllevels != ''
and rsdata.rs_introbjectidentifieralllevels != 'Unknown'
and trdata.weeknumber='1408'
and trdata.tr_plannedgate != ''
and trdata.tr_plannedgate != 'Unknown'
and trdata.tr_plannedgate = variantgates.gate
and trdata.tr_variant = variantgates.variant
and trdata.tr_testexecutionstatus = testatussequence.testatus
and find_in_set(trdata.tr_objectidentifier, (select rsdata.rs_introbjectidentifieralllevels))
order by
rs_variant ASC,
weeknumber ASC,
rs_moduleid ASC,
rs_objectidentifier ASC,
tr_testversion ASC,
tr_plannedgate ASC,
tr_vnvmethod ASC,
tesequencenr DESC;
```

Output from explain query:

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 PRIMARY variantgates ALL Variant_2,Variant NULL NULL NULL 87 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1 PRIMARY trdata ref TR_Variant,WeekNumber TR_Variant 23 remets.variantgates.Variant 5226 Using where
1 PRIMARY testatussequence eq_ref PRIMARY,TEStatus PRIMARY 22 remets.trdata.TR_TestExecutionStatus 1
1 PRIMARY rsdata ref RSDataSI1,RSDataUI2,WeekNumber RSDataUI2 7 const 75658 Using where
1 PRIMARY module ref ModuleUI1 ModuleUI1 11 remets.rsdata.RS_ModuleID 10 Using where; Using index
2 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL No tables used
```

The details of the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `rsdata` (
`RS_Variant` varchar(20) default 'Unknown',
`RS_ModuleID` varchar(8) default 'Unknown',
`RS_ObjectIdentifier` varchar(50) default 'Unknown',
`RS_ObjectType` varchar(20) default 'Unknown',
`WeekNumber` varchar(4) default '9999',
`RS_ReviewStatus` varchar(12) default 'Unknown',
`RS_Priority` varchar(20) default 'Unknown',
`RS_PlannedGate` varchar(10) default 'Unknown',
`RS_VnVMethod` varchar(50) default 'Unknown',
`RS_Datasheet` varchar(1) default NULL,
`RS_RSLinks` int(11) default '0',
`RS_TSLinks` int(11) default '0',
`RS_ReqLinked` varchar(10) default 'Unknown',
`RS_VnVLinked` varchar(10) default 'Unknown',
`RS_InRSObjectIdentifierOneLevel` varchar(500) default 'Unknown',
`RS_InTSObjectIdentifierOneLevel` varchar(500) default 'Unknown',
`RS_InTSObjectIdentifierAllLevels` varchar(750) default 'Unknown',
`RS_InTRObjectIdentifierAllLevels` varchar(750) default 'Unknown',
UNIQUE KEY `RSDataUI1` (`RS_Variant`,`RS_ModuleID`,`RS_ObjectIdentifier`,`WeekNumber`),
KEY `RSDataSI1` (`RS_ModuleID`,`WeekNumber`),
KEY `RSDataUI2` (`WeekNumber`,`RS_Variant`,`RS_ModuleID`,`RS_ObjectIdentifier`),
KEY `WeekNumber` (`WeekNumber`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `trdata` (
`TR_Variant` varchar(20) default NULL,
`TR_ModuleID` varchar(8) default NULL,
`TR_ObjectIdentifier` varchar(50) default NULL,
`TR_ObjectType` varchar(20) default 'Unknown',
`WeekNumber` varchar(4) default '9999',
`TR_ReviewStatus` varchar(12) default 'Unknown',
`TR_Priority` varchar(20) default 'Unknown',
`TR_PlannedGate` varchar(10) default 'Unknown',
`TR_VnVMethod` varchar(50) default 'Unknown',
`TR_TestVersion` varchar(12) default 'Unknown',
`TR_TestExecutionStatus` varchar(20) default 'Unknown',
UNIQUE KEY `TR_Variant` (`TR_Variant`,`TR_ModuleID`,`TR_ObjectIdentifier`,`WeekNumber`),
KEY `TRDataSI1` (`TR_ModuleID`,`WeekNumber`),
KEY `WeekNumber` (`WeekNumber`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `module` (
`ModuleID` varchar(8) default NULL,
`ModuleType` varchar(5) default NULL,
`ModuleName` varchar(50) default NULL,
`ModuleNameLng` varchar(250) default NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `ModuleUI1` (`ModuleID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `variantgates` (
`Variant` varchar(20) default NULL,
`GateGroup` varchar(20) default NULL,
`GateSequenceNr` int(11) default NULL,
`Gate` varchar(10) default NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `Variant_2` (`Variant`,`GateGroup`,`GateSequenceNr`),
KEY `Variant` (`Variant`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `testatussequence` (
`TESequenceNr` int(11) NOT NULL,
`TEStatus` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY (`TEStatus`),
UNIQUE KEY `TEStatus` (`TEStatus`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: any indexes? JOIN explicitly and use indexes I guess

Comment: absolutely you should index your tables

Comment: tables are indexed - you can see the indexing in the last code snippet

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that come to mind:

- DISTINCT often indicates that a select statement is not written well.
  Why combine many, many records and then have to remove them in the
  end?
- Why do you join table module? Only to guarantee that such a matching record exists? Then why not use an exits clause?
- Why do you join table variantgates? Same questions.
- Both trdata and rsdata shall have weeknumber='1408'. This seems to be a criteria wich really helps narrowing your data. Is there an index on that column for both tables? If not, create them.
- As trdata and rsdata shall both have weeknumber='1408', you should hint that this is somthing that links the tables: and trdata.weeknumber = rsdata.weeknumber. (I know this is implicitly so already, but making it explicit can help the dbms build the join.)
- Can you have positive lists for rs_reviewstatus, rs_introbjectidentifieralllevels and tr_plannedgate rather than negative lists? I.e. something like rsdata.rs_reviewstatus in ('Open', 'Accepted')? Then you could use indexes here, too, in order to speed up your query.
- At last back to DISTINCT: Why do you use it here? Why can there be duplicates? Is it because of the tables module and variantgates? Or is there still another reason?

Comment: I join to the tables module and variantgates to filter out some potential conflicts later when I process the output. I did try leaving these joins out before and it made very little difference in execution time. Still, I should try leaving them out again and handle exceptions differently in the other php code if it saves query execution time.

Comment: trdata and tsdata both have keys on weeknumber.

Comment: interesting idea about positive lists. I will definitely try that.

Comment: DISTINCT is used in the query due to possible multiples created by joining to variantgates .... as per previous comment, I will try taking this join out and handling possible duplicates in the php code following this query.       -->Thanks for your suggestions and sorry for the multiple comments but for some reason my Enter key is not working in this forum.